# Displaying more than 3 Dashboards on Home Page

Tags: dashboard, home-page-component

We're supposed to display the following items on the Home Page:

```
- My Open Cases
- Open Cases for Orders
- Open Cases for Service Requests
- DashBoard for Open cases by Status
```

So, we have created Dashboards for them and are unable to place over home page as it doesn't support adding more than 3 dashboards.

> Can we go for merging some components listed above or there's a way I
>   could add them via `iFrame` or so?

I don't want to go for VF Page creation for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to accomplish this is through a Visualforce page and the recent changes to Homepage Components with HTML not allowing markup codes makes the need for Visualforce a requirement to accomplish this. In messing around with this you would think it would be straight forward but my iframe code kept forwarding my homepage to the dashboard itself...maybe someone can chime in as to what I'm missing.

```
<apex:page >

<iframe id="iframeID" src="/01ZC0000000zB11?isdtp=vw"/>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

After spring 15 release iframe is not supported by salesforce.

So we can use location.href in Vf page to place dashboards in Home page component.

Comment: But does it incorporate all the features of a Dashboard. Or its just a screen shot?

Answer (score -1):

you can use location.href ="";
 in visual force page to resolve the issue.

Comment: How does this resolve the issue ?